# jQuery on click inside function(global)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this jQuery on click function work inside a `function(global)`? If I move it outside it would work. Could anyone explain a little the `function(global)` and how to fix this issue ? :D Thanks!

```
   (function (global) {
        $( "#buttonID" ).click(function() {
          alert( "Button clicked." );
        }.bind(this));
    })(window);
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as the click event registered, no matter where you write, it works. You wrote self executing function and the click registered.

Comment: Oh .. well it turned out I didn't have the document.ready before :)